# NFC on android with QT 5.7

Tags: android, c++, qt, nfc

I have a problem with NFC on android lollopop using Qt 5.7.

I am trying to create an app that reacts to "tag discovered" while running, but does not care about tags while the app is not running. This is sort of a hello-world of NFC.

Problem is that QNearFieldManager seems to work ok but targetDetected signals are not firing. I suspect that the problem is within android and/or AndroidManifest.xml since rest of the code is very simple. I have not put all of the code here since there are some unrelated parts, mostly about ui and such. It seems that this portion should work regardles of "hello-world" qml showing on screen. I am just trying to get "Tag Detected" to print in debug while app is focused and tag is detected.

I know that nfc-related intents are missing in AndroidManifest.xml but it only made my app re-launch while reading tags. Documentation also states that intents are used only when background actions are required.

Please advice :)

```
#include "mynfc.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyNFC>("omat.kirjastot.nfc", 1, 0, "MyNFC");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the code from my constructor that initiates the manager and connects the signals:

```
MyNFC::MyNFC(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNearFieldManager(this);

    // Both of these return "true"
    qDebug() << "manager->isAvailable(); == " << manager->isAvailable();
    qDebug() << "manager->startTargetDetection(); == " << manager->startTargetDetection();

    // These signals I am waiting for, but they never fire
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(targetDetected(QNearFieldTarget*)),
            this, SLOT(targetDetected(QNearFieldTarget*)));
}
void MyNFC::targetDetected(QNearFieldTarget *target)
{
    qDebug() << "tag found....";

    if (!target)
        return;
}
```

Here is some of what I have in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```